# Is this a valid proof for $a+b<0\bigwedge ab>c \implies a+b\pm\mathrm{Re}\left[\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4(ab-c)}\right]<0$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I would like to show that 
$$a+b<0\bigwedge ab>c \implies a+b\pm\mathrm{Re}\left[\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4(ab-c)}\right]<0$$ 
for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}.$

Here is my proof:

> \begin{align*}
>     a+b<0 \bigwedge ab>c &\implies a+b\pm \mathrm{Re}\left[\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4(ab-c)}<0 \,\right] \\[-5pt]
>     \Updownarrow\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad&\\[-5pt]
>     a+b<0 \bigwedge ab>c &\implies|a+b|>\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4(ab-c)},
> \end{align*}
>
> which is true since $4(ab-c)>0.$ Here it has been used that if the argument of the square root is negative, it becomes purely imaginary and hence $a+b\pm0<0$ is true.

Is this a good way to write this? My concern is that I've used the inequalities on the left to manipulate and simplify the one on the right. Is this okay?

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of numbers are $$a,b,c$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Reals, as stated. Or did you mean w.r.t. some other property?

Answer (score 0):

if we squaring the last inequality we get $$0>-4(ab-c)$$ which is true since $$ab-c>0$$ which is true.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I think that is the argument I'm making (otherwise I couldn't invoke the triangle inequality). However, my question is more concerning the notation, i.e., whether or not I can manipulate the inequality on the right using the ones on the left and use this as a proof. I'm sorry if the question is not clear in this regard.

Comment: Btw, I have edited the question to use your version instead of trying to use the triangle inequality, so thank you for that.